# How do I create a Route53 healthcheck for a private API Gateway which uses a VPC Endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

Id like to learn how I can create a set of resources in AWS such that a Route53 healthcheck can run HTTPS checks on a ***private*** API Gateway RestAPI/HTTPAPI. The API Gateway API uses a VPC Endpoint and is *private* (not regional, nor edge optimized)

Currently on the Route53 documentation I dont see anywhere if running checks on private endpoints is possible. Is it possible/supported?
If so, how exactly can I set this up? I am happy to use cloud formation, Powershell script, or even Terraform if such a feature is supported.

Answer (score 1):

> I dont see anywhere if running checks on private endpoints is possible. Is it possible/supported?

Its not possible to directly test these checks, as R53 health checkers [use internet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/health-checks-types.html) to check the health of an endpoint:

> At regular intervals that you specify, Route 53 submits automated requests **over the internet** to your application, server, or other resource to verify that it's reachable, available, and functional.

The only workaround that I can think of is to create R53 health checks that monitor CloudWatch Alarms:

> You can create CloudWatch alarms that monitor the **status of CloudWatch metrics**, such as the number of throttled read events for an Amazon DynamoDB database or the number of Elastic Load Balancing hosts that are considered healthy.

Comment: For the workaround you mentioned having healthcheck monitor cloudwatch alarms. This begs the question: How exactly would I trigger an alarm? What mechanism exactly would be used here? Like, a lambda?

Comment: @jbooker Its application specific. For example, if your application generates any logs to CloudWatch Logs, you can setup metric filter to search for errors in the logs, and the create an alarm based on the filter. This alarm would be used as a source of a health check in R53.

Comment: So just log from lambda response codes from endpoints, and setup cloudwatch to have an alarm if logs contain 4xx,5xx ?

Comment: @jbooker Yes, this would work. But are you sure that you need R53 health checks for that? It seems to be redundant for me, especially if this is private API. What do you wish to achieve by having R53 health checks for private API?

Comment: The value of a health check seems equally as important for a private api endpoint as it is for a public api endpoint. It’s the value of endpoint returning success.

Comment: How exactly can I create an alarm based on a cloudwatch log file text? For example, if I have a log with a field "Status" with value "Unhealthy"

Comment: @jbooker You have to create [metric filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringLogData.html) based on your logs.

Comment: I'm thinking instead of creating metric alarms based on logs, just create alarm based on http response code and base alarms on API Gateway instead!